# Is there a tool, which will give information about a sqlite query performance to help in index creation?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've seen the sql server execution plan and the mysql explain, which give details about where queries are not performing as well as they might. I think I need to create some indexes, but I'm not sure where.

Is there a tool for sqlite ?

Don't mind if its on the mac or windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has a [built-in query explain statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html).  You probably want [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).